# How to idiomatically log auth information with middleware

Tags: http, logging, go, middleware

Suppose I'm building a Go web app, with the following requirements:

- Auth middleware that may issue an HTTP response (in case of error)
- Logging middleware should log normal request information (request URL, response status, response size, etc), along with the authentication information (i.e. the authenticated user name)
- Idiomatic uses of `context.Context`

At first blush, this seems easy:

```
r.Use(authMiddleware)
r.Use(loggingMiddleware)
// Other middlewares/routes
```

But this fails if the authMiddleware issues a 400, 401, 403, or similar error, because then the logging middleware is never called.

So a re-order seems appropriate:

```
r.Use(loggingMiddleware)
r.Use(authMiddleware)
// Other middlewares/routes
```

But now, assuming I set the auth information using `context.WithValue()`, the logger has no knowledge of the authentication information. It could still log the HTTP response code, size, etc, but not the authenticated user, etc.

This leads to what feels like a very convoluted solution:

```
r.Use(injectAuthPlaceholder)
r.Use(loggingMiddleware)
r.Use(authMiddleware)
```

Where `injectAuthPlaceholder` does something like:

```
var user *string
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, userKey, user)
```

Then `authMiddleware` sets the user with:

```
userPtr = ctx.Value(userKey).(*string)
*userPtr = authedUsername
```

This has the effect of giving the logger access to the authenticated username, but it requires a two-part auth mechanism, it seems to violate idiomatic use of `context.Context`, and it just feels gross.

What is a more idiomatic solution to this chicken-and-egg problem?

Comment: Why r.Use(loggingMiddleware) never called in error case? Looks like it will as code written sequentially. What at all r.Use() means, you didn't explain your middleware model?

Comment: Because a middleware that has served a response will return, rather than calling `next.ServeHTTP(w,r)`.  So once a middleware responds, the chain is broken. (Otherwise you end up with the subsequent middleware/handlers attempting to send a duplicate response, which won't work properly, and will warn of writing on a hijacked connection, etc)

Comment: I think all middleware/handlers in chain should be called anyway but there behaviour should depend of request.Context.Err() or some other cancellation mechanism.

Comment: That's an interesting approach... I don't think it's within my power to demand that all middlewares behave that way, but maybe with the ones I control will be enough.

Comment: What makes you want to split these two middlewares in the first place? It seems to me like they are both related to the same logic (authentication).

Comment: @basgys: Primarily the fact that logging and auth have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Flimzy It is like comparing oranges and apples. Logging is about recording events that occur in your app. Logs are not a part of your domain, but rather solve a technical problem. `loggingMiddleware` existence is bound to `authMiddleware`, because it logs auth events. Without auth there would not be any auth logs.

Comment: Configuring auth involves providing a user database, crypt methods, secrets, etc.  Configuring loging involves providing a logging format and logging destination (such as a file, or remote server). There is 0 overlap between these. They are related in the same way that the HTTP request is related to logging. If it makes sense to merge logging and auth middlewares, then it makes sense to merge logging and request handling. And everything else.

Comment: But are you logging authentication events in `loggingMiddleware` or configuring logging? I don't get it anymore. I guess it is hard to judge without looking at the whole code.

Comment: I'm logging requests, which include authentication information, as well as other relevant information (requested URL, response code, response size, etc)

Comment: I've updated the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm logging requests, which include authentication information, as well as other relevant information (requested URL, response code, response size, etc)

From what I understand in the logic you have put in these two middlewares, I have the feeling that the logging middleware mixes concerns. I think the HTTP request information logs should be separated from the authentication logs.

As I said, logging is about recording events that occur in your app that are relevant to you. Also, logs need context to be relevant and thus need to have an intimate knowledge about what they log.

> Configuring auth involves providing a user database, crypt methods, secrets, etc. Configuring loging involves providing a logging format and logging destination (such as a file, or remote server). There is 0 overlap between these. They are related in the same way that the HTTP request is related to logging. **If it makes sense to merge logging and auth middlewares, then it makes sense to merge logging and request handling. And everything else.**

Yes, middlewares are a bit like go packages. Just like the standard go packages, I would not split them based on their abstraction layer, but rather based on the part of the domain they solve. So if I have a package `auth`, I would add the all the authentication logic in it, from the domain models, down to the transport layer (e.g. http). I highly recommend you this [excellent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twcDf_Y2gXY) from `Marcus Olsson` about DDD applied to Go.

**Middleware examples**

```
func mwLogging(next MiddlewareFunc) MiddlewareFunc {
    return func(c *Context) {
        c.Ctx.Trace("h.http.req.start", "Request start",
            log.String("method", c.Method),
            log.String("path", c.Path),
            log.String("user_agent", c.Req.Header.Get("User-Agent")),
        )

        next(c)

        c.Ctx.Trace("h.http.req.end", "Request end",
            log.Int("status", c.Res.Code()),
            log.Duration("duration", time.Since(c.StartTime)),
        )
    }
}

func mwAuth(next MiddlewareFunc) MiddlewareFunc {
    return func(c *http.Context) {
        // Just an example
        session, err := Auth(c.Req.Header.Get("Authorization"))
        if err != nil {
            c.Ctx.Warning("http.auth.error", "Authentication failed", log.Error(err))
            c.Res.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
            return
        }

        // You could store the session in context here                
        context.WithValue(ctx, "session", session)
        next(c)
    }
}
```

Shameless plug: the [logging middleware](https://github.com/stairlin/lego/blob/master/handler/http/middlewares.go#L62) is taken from [stairlin/lego](https://github.com/stairlin/lego).